# Can't get regex to function correctly

Tags: javascript, regex, shopify

I'm currently doing some custom checkout fields for a customer using Shopify. They have got me to add a VAT field for customers using their EU site which has been working great. However, their accounts team is having issues as some customers are entering random data in. So I thought I'd try get some sort of verification system going using regex however I can't seem to get it to work.
Below is my HTML code and the snippet of JS used for this check/error message.

```js
    // VAT Field Checks
    $("#checkout_vat_number").on("keypress", function(evt) {
        var theEvent = evt || window.event;
        var len_val = $(this).val().length;
        if (theEvent.type === 'paste') {
            key = event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
        } else {
            var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
            key = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
        }
      
        if(len_val < 11){ 
          var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{9}$/g; //Checks to make sure code is 2 letters and then 9 numbers
          if( !regex.test (key) ) {
            $("#error-for-vat-text").show();
            $("#error-for-vat-text").text("Please add your 2 digit country code and 9 digit tax number");
            theEvent.returnValue = false;
            if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
          } else {
            $("#error-for-vat-text").hide();
            $("#error-for-vat-text").text("");
          }
        } else {
             theEvent.returnValue = false;
            if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
        }

    });
```

```html
<div id="checkout_vat">
  <p class="section__text">Fill out your VAT number including 2 digit country code and 9 numbers, excluding any special characters.</p>
  <div class="fieldset" id="vat">
    <div data-address-field="vat" id="vat_field" class="field field--required">
      <div class="field__input-wrapper field__input-wrapper--icon-right"><label class="field__label field__label--visible" for="checkout_vat_number">VAT Number</label>
        <input placeholder="VAT Number" autocomplete="vat number" autocorrect="off" class="field__input field__input--numeric" aria-describedby="error-for-vat" aria-invalid="true" aria-required="true" size="30" type="text" value="" pattern=".{11,11}" name="checkout[attributes][VAT Number]"
          id="checkout_vat_number">
        <input type="hidden" name="checkout[attributes][Agreed that responsible for any import duties/taxes and/or associated costs incurred.]" value="" id="checkout_duties_taxes_input">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="field__message field__message--error" id="error-for-vat-text"></p>
    <p class="field__message field__message--error" id="error-for-vat" style="display:none;">Enter a VAT number</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I believe my regex of `^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{9}$/g` is correct (2 letters followed by 9 numbers exactly) however I can't seem to find what else I have done wrong. Bear in mind JS is not my strong suit so something may be very wrong.
Even if there was a way to modify the `String.fromCharCode` to only accept 2 letters and 9 numbers but I'm not sure?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: It says `keyCode` is not defined. Also, the problem is that you are trying to match the currently pressed (*single*) key against the `/^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{9}$/` pattern that expects to match a string of 11 chars.

Comment: How would I go about fixing that? I'm honestly a little lost and have been staring at it for the past 2 hours.

Comment: No idea what your expectations are. Search for "live input validation with regex jquery", or something like that.

Comment: Checked the RegEx and it seems to work. At least the code snippet $("#error-for-vat-text").html("...") gives me the error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).html is not a function" you may use $("#error-for-vat-text").innerHTML = "..."

Answer (score 0):

Use a `keyup` listener. You regular expression can be simplified, but basically it's not wrong. Here's a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you can work with. It uses [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to handle the event.

```js
document.addEventListener(`keyup`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === `demo`) {
    document.querySelector(`#validate`).textContent = 
    evt.target.value.trim().length < 1 
    ? `start typing...` 
    : !/^[a-z]{2}\d{9}$/i.test(evt.target.value) 
      ? `not ready yet` 
      : `yep, there we are!`;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 2rem;
  font: 12px/15px verdana, arial;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>We expect 2 characters followed by 9 digits, e.g. AG120981212.</div>
  <br><input id="demo"> <span id="validate">start typing&hellip;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't really know what you've here (as I said I'm a JS noob), however I'll try get it work with my code. Let's hope for the best!

Comment: Let's hope so indeed. Just tinker with the code, if necessary use someting like [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) to experiment